# Laravel 5.1 localhost:8000 nada aparece

Tags: php, laravel

Instalei o `'laravel 5.1'` segui os passos no doc, adicionei algumas coisas no `'gulpfile.js'` blz, mas quando rodo o `'php artisan serve'` e rodo `'http://localhost:8000/'` nada aparece, fiz um teste tambem criei um arquivo `'sass'` e rodei o `'gulp'` porem nada foi compilado para dentro da pasta `public`, o que devo configurar mais? Eu vou usar ele para me auxiliar na construção de sites sou front, como agora o back é so php preciso usar um FW.

Pessoal, acho que o problema é com a permissao de pastas, por isso nada funciona, alguem que tipo de permissao dou e como? uso mac yosemite.

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou configurar seu PHP.ini com `display_errors = On`. Essa tela branca pode ser gerada por um erro fatal seguido de `display_erros = Off`!

Comment: Veja no log de erros na aplicação se aparece algo lá. Provavelmente está faltando configurar as permissões em algum lugar.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti  acho que o problema é realmente permissoes, editei a pergunta ... E não estou achando o arquivo laravel.log  não esta no projeto na pasta de logs.

Comment: @Erick ao rodar php artisan serve aparece isso? http://i.stack.imgur.com/dFB4O.png

Comment: @gmsantos um dos problemas resolvi, pois o usuario estava como root e nao como o meu usuario ai consegui mudar e agora ta parecendo a pagina LARAVEL 5 ....  Mas tenho um outro problema o gulp nao esta compilando e criando as pastas dentro de public como mencionei na pergunta